# Add feature to SelfControl software : choose network interface to block

Tags: macos, network, wifi, productivity

[SelfControl](http://selfcontrolapp.com) is an open source software to block Internet connection for a time period. However, it blocks connection from ALL network interfaces. 
**I'm looking for someone that would like to add a function in order to allow the user to choose the network interface to block**. The goal is to block only the WiFi connection and let the ethernet working.
The source code is available at [github](https://github.com/slambert/selfcontrol/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried contacting [Charlie Stigler](http://charliestigler.com/) or [Steve Lambert](http://visitsteve.com/), the creators of SelfControl? An offer to fund the feature would also likely help.

I expect you will get a better response from your [enhancement request](https://github.com/slambert/selfcontrol/issues/178) on the SelfControl [issues page](https://github.com/slambert/selfcontrol/issues). More potential developers will see requests there and others will be able to back the issue to highlight its potential.

Comment: I've just did... waiting for an answer!

Comment: Looks like they're still using the `ipfw` tool, which is deprecated. If they update to `pfctl`, then they can use the `-i` flag, which allows restriction to only one interface.

Comment: Well, it seems they have updated to code in order to use `pfctl` now, but there are a lot of higher issues on their list! Maybe I'll find a developer that could integrate this function to SelfControl...